# How can I send data from bottom sheet to parent widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, callback, widget

I have list of products in bottom sheet, when I choose any product I want to parent's widget to add it, unfortunately my product adds only after hot reload, or when I create a new route from bottom sheet to parent's widget, how can I solve this problem, any ideas? Here is the part of the bottom sheet code

```
    class IceBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {


  const IceBottomSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IceBottomSheetState createState() => _IceBottomSheetState();
}

class _IceBottomSheetState extends State<IceBottomSheet> {
  final _model = ProductWidgetsModel();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> productWidgetList = [];

    products.forEach((product) =>
        productWidgetList.add(SingleProductWidget(product: product)));

    return Provider(
      model: _model,
      child: Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 16,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          
          crossAxisCount: 2, children: productWidgetList),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SingleProductWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Product product;

  
  const SingleProductWidget({Key? key, required this.product})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SingleProductWidget> createState() => _SingleProductWidgetState();
}

class _SingleProductWidgetState extends State<SingleProductWidget> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of(context)?.model;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: 
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 100,
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
               
                image: DecorationImage(
                  
                  image: widget.product.image,
                ),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: model?.idSelected == widget.product.id
                      ? Colors.yellow
                      : Colors.grey,
                  width: 5.0,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                ),
              ),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                model?.idSelected = widget.product.id;
              //   Route route =
              //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BerryPage(context,));
              // Navigator.push(context, route);
              if(model?.idSelected == 1){

                  menuRow.removeAt(2);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  choice.insert(2, Adds(id: 102, name: 'Холодок', img: 'https://autogear.ru/misc/i/gallery/73434/2759438.jpg'));

              }
              
              }),
            ),
          ),
```

And here is the part of parent's widget code, it is inside GestureDetector

```
  else if (index == 2){
                setState(() {
                  
                });
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  
                  
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext builder) {
      return Container(
          height: 250,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),Row(
                children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.25 + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.12),
                  child: Text(
                    'Холодок',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Newfont',
                      fontSize: 22,
                    ),
                                    ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.25,),
                
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.close),onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context);},)
              ],
              ),
              
              Divider(),
               IceBottomSheet(),
            ],
          ));
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you open the `BottomSheet` you have to add `await` before it, so when you call `Navigator.pop(context, data_you_want_to_pass_to_parent)` it will wait for some data to be returned.

```
final data = await openBottomSheet();
```

inside the bottomSheet when you want to close, just pass the the desired data as so

```
Navigator.pop(context, data_you_want_to_pass_to_parent);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13742810/m-m-hasibuzzaman, so when I do Navigator.pop(context,choice.insert(...)) there is a error such as insert is a void type, so I cannot send data which I need(

Comment: choice.insert(...) this is a function with return type void, but the navigator return data argument needs a data so it throws the error, as void does not return anything

Comment: This worked for me in 3.16.